# Can't get Bootstrap pills to change and display content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have tried everything I have found so far, unsure what's left. I just want to have two pills and change the content displayed depending on which one is clicked. Simple enough. I have tried copying exactly what is in the Bootstrap docs, as well as many other websites' solutions, all to no avail.

The code in my header.ejs file includes...

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- BOOTSTRAP AND CSS  -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

The code on the page in question is:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">Test content 1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">Test content 2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">Test content 3</div>
</div>
```

But I have tried a few different solutions to try and solve this.

The bottom of that same file now also includes:

```
<script>
        $(".nav li a").on("click", function() {
            $(".nav li a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });

    </script>
```

Now this has made it so that the pill I click on changes color to the one I clicked on (which didn't use to happen), but the content displayed remains the same.

I am so lost. Willing to learn, but I have read that many websites and articles and videos to no avail yet.

Comment: Can you create a codepen?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `data-bs-target` attribute on the anchor elements. this attribute should have the `id` of the pane that it is connected to. I have added the first one for you.

```
<a class="nav-link active" data-bs-target="#pills-home" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
```

Comment: that didn't seem to do anything. The targets match my tab-panes correctly. Any other thoughts?